# create sql oracle view, using a join, then use orderby and then rownum <=1

Tags: join, view, sql-order-by, rownum

what I am trying to do is create a view that joins 2 tables, persons and documents. There will be many documents per person but I only want the most recent issued document for that person. So I figure I join the 2 tables, which works fine, then I try to order the issued date from documents to get most recent and then get the top in that row. To me it makes sense but I get the  following error

```
 that the SQL code is not complete
```

and my code is as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW DisplayPersons
  AS
    SELECT 
      P.PERSON_ID AS "Person_ID",
      P.SURNAME AS "Surname",
      ...
      FROM PERSONS P
    LEFT JOIN
      DOCUMENTS D ON D.RECEIVED_BY = P.SURNAME||', '||P.INITIALS
      ORDER BY D.ISSUED_DATE DESC 
      WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause needs to come before `ORDER BY`.